# JavaScript Pattern

Tags: javascript

I really need help with this:

Write a JavaScript program to display the following patterns:

1. ```
   *
   **
   ***
   ****
   *****
   ```
2. ```
   1
   22
   333
   4444
   55555
   ```

I am aware that these patterns share the same concept but I just can't write an algorithm for these patterns.

This is what I've tried:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jdfkdfkldfko</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var x = new
            document.write(+"<br/>");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Are you sure you want to create an HTML output? Shouldn't you be printing the pattern in javascript console?

Comment: I want to create a javascript output using "document. write"

Answer (score -1):

We can create a function that can do both.

```
var createPyramid = function(steps, displayCharacter = null) {
    var pyramid = '';
    for (var step = 1; step <= steps; step++) {
        for(var i = 1; i <= step; i++){
            //display number if displayCharacter is not provided
            pyramid = pyramid.concat(displayCharacter?displayCharacter.toString():step.toString());
        }
        pyramid = pyramid.concat('\n');
    }

    console.log(pyramid);
};
```

Then you can call the same function for:

1. `createPyramid(5, '*');`

expected output:

```
*
** 
*** 
**** 
*****
```

2. `createPyramid(5);`

expected output:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

Answer (score -2):

I have found the answer, I have stored it in an array called x.

```
<script>




    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {




        var x = ["*", "**", "***", "****", "*****", ]




        document.write(x[i] + "<br/>");




    }




    for (var a = 0; a < 5; a++) {




        var y = ["1", "22", "333", "4444", "55555", ]




        document.write(y[a] + "<br/>");




    }








</script>
```

Comment: This is almost certainly not how you are expected to solve this. In the end, you could just as well hard-code the entire output.